# How do I properly format a django ORM query's sql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

In case my question is too myopic, my 10,000 ft goal is to capture database queries made across a number of read only screens using the [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client).

When I view the sql using `django.db.connection.queries` none of the sql querys' parameters are quoted. The same is true if I call `.query` on a single ORM query. Is there a way to get django to generate valid sql?

```
In [23]: str(MyModel
   ....:     .objects
   ....:     .filter(created_date__lt=datetime.datetime.now())
   ....:     .query)
Out[23]: 'SELECT `main_mymodel`.`id`, `main_mymodel`.`name`, `main_mymodel`.`created_date` WHERE `main_mymodel`.`created_date` < 2015-11-25 '
```

My underlying DB is MySQL if that makes a difference.

Comment: Run it into https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse ?

Comment: Did you actually test if that is valid SQL by passing it to the server?

Comment: @KlausD. I tested that it isn't valid. In the example above 2015-11-25 gets interpreted as integer subtraction not a date. If it is a datetime column there ends up being a space and the colons really throw off MySQL.